# Calculating the parameters for orthographic matrix from perspective matrix

Tags: opengl, graphics, linear-algebra

The following two methods are taken from the ios GLKit framework:

```
GLK_INLINE GLKMatrix4 GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(float left, float right,
                                                 float bottom, float top,
                                                 float nearZ, float farZ)
{
    float ral = right + left;
    float rsl = right - left;
    float tab = top + bottom;
    float tsb = top - bottom;
    float fan = farZ + nearZ;
    float fsn = farZ - nearZ;

    GLKMatrix4 m = { 2.0f / rsl, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                     0.0f, 2.0f / tsb, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                     0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f / fsn, 0.0f,
                     -ral / rsl, -tab / tsb, -fan / fsn, 1.0f };

    return m;
}

GLK_INLINE GLKMatrix4 GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(float fovyRadians, float aspect, float nearZ, float farZ)
{
    float cotan = 1.0f / tanf(fovyRadians / 2.0f);

    GLKMatrix4 m = { cotan / aspect, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                     0.0f, cotan, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                     0.0f, 0.0f, (farZ + nearZ) / (nearZ - farZ), -1.0f,
                     0.0f, 0.0f, (2.0f * farZ * nearZ) / (nearZ - farZ), 0.0f };

    return m;
}
```

I would like to smoothly move from perspective view to ortho view and vice-versa. How should i calculate the correct parameters for ortho matrix, given the perspective matrix and parameters?

Comment: With a perspective projection, the viewing volume will be represented by a pyramd frustum, while for an orthogonal projection, it will be some cuboid. SO you can in principle smoothly morph between them. However, the question is still quite unspecific. Do you consider both the final ortho matrix and the final projection matrix as given?

Comment: No, i have one given, and trying to figure out the second matrix. I want to transform from given perspective matrix to an orthographic matrix in a way that will 'look good', so it would not be too jumpy.

Comment: Well, it is very ambigous then. You can basically select any plane at distance z which will be machted between the orthogonal and perspective view. It will alwyas appear "jumpy" for all objects outside such a plane.

Comment: When you want a smooth interpolation between both, the functions you noted are not powerful enough, while 4x4 homogenous matrices allow to do what you want. But during the interpolation, the intersectiong point of the view frustum must be moved away from the eye point, until an othogonal view is reached when that intersection point "reaches" infinity.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. Somewhat on the high end of effort you can expect people to spend on an answer here, IMHO. The simplest approach might be where I think @derhass was also going. Move the viewpoint farther and farther away, reduce the view angle accordingly, until you're almost at an orthogonal projection. Then switch over. But I think you'd have to go *really* far away to avoid a jump at the last step, and might run into precision problems. [TBC due to comment length]

Comment: The more appealing approach is to build projection matrices that are some form of hybrid between perspective and orthogonal, and gradually change the bias between perspective and orthogonal. I think it should be possible, but I haven't done the math.

Comment: Well, given the 8 corner points of the frustum (in eye or world space), it is not really hard to use the 8 corresponding corners of NDC space and the _direct linear transform_ (DLT) algorithm to get a homogenous projection matrix for that. It will also handle the fully orthogonal case. So just blending the 8 corners between frustum and cuboid should be possible without any discontinuity at all. The "switch" between perspecitve and ortho is not really special in homogenous space.

Comment: Just note that any of these _hybrid_ projection matrices can be represented by a "standard" perspective matrix + a translation (which is what I had in mind in my original comment, while @RetoKoradi seem to have interpreted this as moving the viewpoint - and he is also right, as both views are valid, although view point typically defined by the view matrix, while this ends up putting the translation into the projection matrix).

Comment: Yeah, that's where my thought were going. Have a view frustum defined by 8 corners, and gradually change if from a frustum describing a perspective projection into one describing a orthographic projection (which is a box). Then calculate a projection matrix that transforms this frustum into clip coordinates.